# Error while creating bean with spring managed context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat8, java-ee-7

I am running my application in tomcat 8, and i am using spring framework version 4.0.6.

In order to make data manipulation i am required to inject EntityManagerFactory in Repository classes as follows:

```
@PersistenceUnit
EntityManagerFactory efEntityManagerFactory;
```

The configuration of data source is done pragmatically as shown on the following code

```
@Configuration
public class PersistenceJPAConfiguration {

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("*****");
    return dataSource;
}

private Map<String, ?> jpaProperties() {
    Map<String, String> jpaPropertiesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    jpaPropertiesMap.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
    return jpaPropertiesMap;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean
            = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.company.project.dto");
    factoryBean.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaProperties());
    return factoryBean;
}}
```

I am getting the following error message...

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'countryController': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:356)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:484)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1034)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4923)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5215)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1780)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:559)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:515)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.resolveEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:668)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$PersistenceElement.getResourceToInject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:353)
    ... 30 more
```

What are your thoughts...?

Comment: It looks like Spring can't find a bean whose **type** is `EntityManagerFactory`.  (See the last "Caused by".)  Is `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` a subclass of `EntityManagerFactory`?  If so, then change the return type of the bean method to `EntityManagerFactory` so that Spring will find it.  I'm not 100% sure of this, since I get confused by Spring errors a lot.  But please try it.

Comment: I have modified the method to return EntityManagerFactory but i still have the same message... it seems that spring couldn't resolve the DataSource

Comment: Why do you think it couldn't resolve the `DataSource`?  Is it now displaying a different error message that refers to `DataSource`?  The stack trace you provide doesn't have any reference to `DataSource`.  If the error messages are different, please post them (and don't say "I still have the same message").  Just the error messages are enough; we probably don't need the complete stack trace with the line numbers.

Comment: While i was debugging the code is see that instance method of PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor findDefaultEntityManager(String requestingBean) is not finding any default bean and this is the reason why i have the error message, but should the EntityManagerFactory instantiated from configuration class?

Comment: Error message : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beanName': Injection of persistence dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined

Comment: Been a while since I used spring, but I think you need EnableJpaRepositories added to your Configuration for this to work.

Comment: @CrazySabbath The annotation EnableJpaRepositories as is written on spring documentation is used to find the annotated repositories on the specified packaged, hence it is not used for instantiation of EntityManagerFactory. I already configured the datasource on configuration class.